# Referencing a new dynamically created div class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to create a div with a class name, but then reference that div without giving it an ID? Or will there have to be an ID that gets generated? Also, the reason why I'm creating a div is because I'm trying to create a plugin for myself that will potentially have this div repeated every where, however I just want to reference that single div.

For instance:

```
var newDiv = $("<div/>").addClass("newAdded");

$(parent).append(newDiv);

$(newDiv).css("background","purple");
```

Is something like that possible? I know the above code doesn't work, but hopefully that helps illustrate my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference will be retained:

```
// Create a new div and maintain a reference to it
var div = $("<div></div>").addClass("foo");

// Our div is a jQuery object
div.appendTo(parent);

// We still have a reference
div.text( "Text added after the appending has taken place" );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/fwHAB/

Comment: @Majed My pleasure. It's a great question - these types of things can be a little confusing at times. Keep up the great work ;)

Comment: Hey Sampson, I'm revisiting this and I realized you used the `.addClass()` function instead of just adding the class into the div, was there a reason for that? Thanks!

Comment: @Majo0od No specific reason; I typically try to keep my markup clear of my CSS. But other than that, it was muscle memory :) I am updating my answer to use `"<div></div>"` as the HTML string; I believe IE 8 or 7 had issues with the prior approach.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible, and that is the proper way to do it.

`newDiv` is already a jQuery object, so not `$(newDiv)`, but just `newDiv`.

```
newDiv.css("background","purple");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also reference the new div in the append statement.

```
$(parent).append(newDiv).css("background","purple");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the new class you can also reference that variable by class if you lose scope of that JavaScript variable:

```
$('.newAdded').css("background","purple");
```